# Error While generating Report in Microsoft SQL Reporting Service : NOT A VALID DESIGNATOR

Tags: sql, sql-server

I receive the following error in Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder

> Error While generating Report in Microsoft sql Reporting Service : NOT
>   A VALID DESIGNATOR

[image: Error Image]

The following is the image of the query and its output (Dataset)
[image]

Please can any one tell me why is this error occurring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may wish to check your computers regional settings and ensure that the decimal is set to `.`.

This link has more information: [Bug Report Builder 2.0](http://mk-hu.blogspot.co.uk/)

[image]

Comment: Before Posting here I tried this But it did not work . I think I will close the app and restart it .

Comment: @Rish it didn't work until I restarted the ReportBuilder. You should restart it in order that changes be taken into consideration